# The slashes in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to read some php code and was wondering why preg_replace always has the slashes. In the regex's I've written in C++, I don't do the same thing and was wondering why

PHP: `preg_replace('/blah/', '', $str)` but in C++ I'd make a regex with just the string `"blah"`

Can I get some clarification here? What are the start and end slashes for? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are just regex delimiters. From the [PHP manual documentation on Delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace
>   character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (`/`), hash signs (`#`) and
>   tildes (`~`). The following are all examples of valid delimited
>   patterns.

Comment: as the manual says.. `A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.` so it is possible. ^.^

Answer (score 3):

They're delimiters, allowing you to add modifiers, e.g. /blah/i for a case insensitive regex.

The use of slashes comes from perl or shell/sed insofar as I'm aware.

In php, they're not mandatory, in the sense that you can use other characters. For instance, "!blah!i" works too. There also is a special syntax with brackets, which is much less error prone since you don't need to escape it: "{blah}i".

Comment: so, is this the same for C++ regex's as well?

Comment: I'm not sure which flavor the C++ regex use. They're the same as Perl, since the preg_* functions stand for Perl-compatible.